# how do I redirect a location to another but not changing its URL in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am working on a website to display different products, users can access different product page by urls like 'mydomain.com/product/1.html', 'mydomain.com/product/2.html'

but I don't want to present those static html files directly, instead there is a php script will be loaded first at mydomain.com/product.php

so I want to redirect 'mydomain.com/product/1.html' to 'mydomain.com/product.php' but don't change its original url

I tried alias, try_files, return, but all of them rewrite the url to 'mydomain.com/product.php'

I am new to Nginx, this is probably a very simple question, but I have tried to achieve this for couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do it...

The most simple is

```
rewrite ^/product/ /product.php;
```

at the **server** context. Your original request URI (i.e. `/product/1.html`) will be available for `product.php` script as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` array item value.

You can also use `rewrite` directive at the **location** context, this can be slightly (*very* slightly) more performant:

```
location /product/ {
    rewrite ^ /product.php last;
}
```

If you want, you can get product code and pass it to your `product.php` script as a query argument:

```
rewrite ^/product/(.*)\.html$ /product.php?product=$1;
```

or

```
location /product/ {
    rewrite ^/product/(.*)\.html$ /product.php?product=$1 last;
}
```

This way your product code (`1` for the `/product/1.html` URI, `2` for the `/product/2.html` URI, etc.) will be available for `product.php` script as `$_GET['product']` array item value.

You can even define an individual FastCGI handler for this:

```
location /product/ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/product.php;
    fastcgi_pass <fastcgi_upstream_or_socket>;
}
```

(original request URI will be available via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`), or if you want for product code to be available via `$_GET['product']`:

```
location ~ /product/(.*)\.html$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/product.php;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING product=$1;
    fastcgi_pass <fastcgi_upstream_or_socket>;
}
```